# android - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Samsung s5 - 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-support-library, noclassdeffounderror

So far I got this error only for one user, who uses a rooted phone SM-G900R7 Android 4.4.2.

error started to emerge after you upgrade to the library version of android O.

- compileSdkVersion 26
- buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
- minSdkVersion 17
- targetSdkVersion 26

---

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/graphics/drawable/Icon
       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java)
       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:656)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.getExportedPropertyMethods(ViewDebug.java:960)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.exportMethods(ViewDebug.java:1047)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewProperties(ViewDebug.java:997)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewProperties(ViewDebug.java:983)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpView(ViewDebug.java:900)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:870)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dump(ViewDebug.java:793)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dispatchCommand(ViewDebug.java:416)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$W.executeCommand(ViewRootImpl.java:6258)
       at android.view.IWindow$Stub.onTransact(IWindow.java:65)
       at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(NativeStart.java)
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.graphics.drawable.Icon" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.xxxx.xxxx-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.xxxx.xxxx-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java)
       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:656)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.getExportedPropertyMethods(ViewDebug.java:960)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.exportMethods(ViewDebug.java:1047)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewProperties(ViewDebug.java:997)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewProperties(ViewDebug.java:983)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpView(ViewDebug.java:900)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:870)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dump(ViewDebug.java:793)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dispatchCommand(ViewDebug.java:416)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$W.executeCommand(ViewRootImpl.java:6258)
       at android.view.IWindow$Stub.onTransact(IWindow.java:65)
       at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Strange, Icon class was added in api 23, so it should not work below that!

Comment: Also seeing this for just one user, any news on the issue?

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: Same here just on samsung!

Comment: Have the same issue

Comment: Facing a similar issue

Comment: Same issue on Samsung S5 4.4.2

Comment: Has anyone fixed it?